# build failed after installing and enabling Search module inside Orchard 1.10.1

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

after fresh installation of Orchard 1.10.1 (zip version), everything was working but when I installed 'Search' module, instantly Visual Studio 2015 pop-up to reload. So, I reloaded and then again tried to run it but every time I failed. The build has more than 100 errors. I did in 2 separate laptops and every-time getting those error like:

**Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Environment' does not exist in the namespace 'Orchard' (are you missing an assembly reference?) Orchard.Search  C:\Orchard_Source\src\Orchard.Web\Modules\Orchard.Search\ContentAdminMenu.cs    1   Active**

I guess when the search module is going to enable, something is changing and visual studio is unable to load and so finally the errors.....  :(

anybody face the same issues? or anybody knows how to fix this? if please, tell me what I am missing or what I need to follow.

Thanks

Comment: Try run it with Cntrl+F5

Comment: I tried that. but no luck!   :(

Comment: You do not need to install Search, because it comes standard with Orchard. What you probably did is replace a perfectly good module with an old version that's incompatible with your version of Orchard, thereby breaking it. You should restore a backup.